# secure method to pass javascript based md5 value to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, hash

i am trying to write a script for uploading multiple image files which will check for md5 hash for each image file begore uploading to server

code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var log = document.getElementById("hash_log");
var hash_array = [];

$("#screenshot").change(function() {
  handleFiles(this.files);
});
function handleFiles(files) {
    for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var binary = event.target.result;
            var md5_hash = calcMD5(binary).toString()
            hash_array[i]= md5_hash; // array to store hash value
            registerLog(hash_array[i]); // to show hash value, just for testing purpose

            setCookie( 'cookie_'+i, hash_array[i] ); // generate cookie in incremetal order, issue line
        };
        reader.onerror = function() {
            console.error("Could not read the file");
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(files.item(i));
    }
}

// for geneaarted hash values
function registerLog(str, className) {
    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.innerHTML = str;
    elem.className = "alert-message" + (className ? " "  + className : "");
    log.appendChild(elem);
}

// function for setting cookies...
function setCookie(name, value) {
    var argv = setCookie.arguments;
    var argc = setCookie.arguments.length;
    var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;
    var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;
    var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;
    var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + 

        ((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) + 
        ((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) + 
        ((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) + 
        ((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
}
</script>
```

Now hash for image files are generating fine, but in order to compare these values for server side processing

i am using cookies to pass value

now on line 16, code for setting the cookie:

```
        setCookie( 'cookie_'+i, hash_array[i] );
```

so the cookie name should be in incremental orders like : cookie1, cookie2, cookie3 and  so on...
but it sets only cookie3 with the hash value

reason : inside the file read function the i is already set to 3 if 3 files are generated, as it sets to total no of files selected for upload

So overall,  please suggest a solution on how to increment the cookie name value.

I am stuck with it for 2 days now, tried a lot of ways but seems the only way is to post the situation now..

also: is there a better way to pass the variable  value to php other than cookies or hidden input variables.

Comment: Please excuse for the question title as a proper one didn't strike at the time of posting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the loop terminates, the function-level variable i has the value 3, and that's what the `reader.onload` function 'sees'.

You can use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to avoid those scope issues .

Read [this](http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/08/javascript-foreach/) blog post for more info on the subject .

Answer (score 0):

Thaks alexander , your suggestion did work !!

Here what the tinkering required to solve it. I am posting it in case, some other person may get stuck with similar situation.

our issue here was :
 onload file function takes the counter of i to the total no of files selected. in which case, when the following function for setting the cookie name is called:

```
setCookie('cookie_'+index, element);
```

let say 5 files are selected for upload then the index value will already be 5, 
so now the cookie names instead of getting in incremental order, will only set to 'cookie_5'

Here the solution lies with using array.prototype.forEach loop function
this resolves the scope issues of existing index value..

array.forEach(argument) , basically it traverses through each value of the array in order

```
// create an empty array ck_array for entering new hash strings to it
 var ck_array = [];

// main function
function handleFiles(files) {
    for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var binary = event.target.result;
            var md5_hash = calcMD5(binary).toString()
            hash_array[i]= md5_hash; // array to store hash value
            registerLog(hash_array[i]); // to show hash value, just for testing purpose

            // code for array.prototype to work

            ck_array.push(md5_hash);
            if(ck_array.length == x){
                ck_array.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
                    setCookie('ck'+index+': ', element);
                });     
            }
        };
        reader.onerror = function() {
            console.error("Could not read the file");
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(files.item(i));
    }
}
```

And now if we check in for set cookies, cookie names are as ck0, ck1, ck2 with their corresponding md_5 hash values

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/madhvik/vpwLxph9/1/

PS note: 
in the running code of jsfiddle: For simplicity,  a function randomString()  is used to generate a random string instead of calling md5 hash script.